# Proving inequality of line segments in a circle

Tags: geometry, inequality, euclidean-geometry

[image]

> There are 2 intersecting circles with the centers $O_1$ and $O_2$ and the radiuses $r_1$ and $r_2$ respectively ($r_1 \gt r_2$). They have a common segment line $AB$. Also $AC$ is the tangent line of the smaller circle, and $AD$ is the tangent line of the bigger circle.

$\mathbf{Questions:}$ How to prove that $CB\gt AB$ and $AB\lt\frac{CB+BD}{2}$.

$\mathbf{My}$ $\mathbf{approach}:$
I have shown that $\angle CBA = \angle DBA$.
If $\angle ACB = \beta$, then $\angle BO_1O_2 = \angle AO_1O_2 = \beta$. Let $\angle CAO_1 = \alpha$. Then $\angle DAO_2 = \alpha$, because $O_1A \perp DA$ and $O_2A \perp CA$, $\angle CAD$ is common, so $\angle CAO_1 =  \angle DAO_2$. Then the same thing is going on for the smaller one. $\angle BDA = \gamma$. Then $\angle CAB = 90 - \alpha - \beta$ and $\angle DAB = 90 - \alpha - \gamma$, so $\angle CBA = \angle DBA$.

I have also done many other calculations, but I think they are not helpful for this problem.
I can't progress from this point. Please help me to prove them. Thanks in advance.

$\mathbf{Edit:}$ I have also observed the case when $CB$ and $BD$ are aligned and in that case the first statement is true, because $r_1 \gt r_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From inscribed angle theorem we have the following observations:

With respect to the circle $O_1$:

$$\angle BCA=\angle BAD.
$$
With respect to the circle $O_2$:
$$
\angle BDA=\angle BAC.
$$

It follows $\triangle ABD\sim \triangle CBA$. This implies:
$$
\frac{CB}{AB}=\frac{r_1}{r_2}>1\implies CB>AB,\quad \frac{CB}{AB}=\frac{AB}{BD}\implies
AB=\sqrt{CB\cdot BD}<\frac{CB+BD}2,
$$
where the last is AM-GM inequality.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome!